# Android View won't scroll with swipe gesture and won't scroll.  Using ListView with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, swipe

I'm using a custom `ArrayAdapter` for my `ListView`. I have a `CheckBox` on the left and two `TextView` items to the right of the `CheckBox`, stacked on top of each other.  I'm also using a custom `android:listSelector`.

I insert 8 items into my custom `ListView` in `MyActivity` `onCreate` method.

I am able to select a row of the list so that it changes color and I am also able to check and uncheck the checkbox.  However, the view doesn't respond to a vertical swipe, nor does it ever give the items focus when I hover over the items with my fingers. I can scroll if I simultaneously click the item and scroll down with my other finger, but this isn't want I want.  Have I somehow clobbered the vertical swipe gesture?

I want to point out that there are NO `ScrollView` objects in my problem. Most of the posts out there have to do with folks putting `ListView` objects inside of `ScrollView`, visa-versa.

My suspicion is that something is wrong in my layout and/or something is wrong with the way I'm assigning the focus in the layout and in the code.

Here is my main Activity code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    private ListView lv;
    private TextView titleDisplay;
    private TextView locationDisplay;
    private ArrayList<TalkItem> m_talks = null;
    private MyListView m_adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.session_view);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sessionlist);    
        titleDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sessiontitle);
        locationDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sessionlocation);

        m_talks = new ArrayList<TalkItem>();
        this.m_adapter = new MyListView(this, R.layout.sessionlistitem, m_talks);
        lv.setAdapter(this.m_adapter); 

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //TODO: do something
            }
        });

        //set title and location display
        titleDisplay.setText("TITLE");
        locationDisplay.setText("LOCATION");
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first1", "last1", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first2", "last2", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first3", "last3", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first4", "last4", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first5", "last5", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first6", "last6", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first7", "last7", false));
        m_talks.add(new TalkItem("first8", "last8", false));

    }

    public class MyListView extends ArrayAdapter<TalkItem> {

        private ArrayList<TalkItem> items;

        public MyListView(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
                ArrayList<TalkItem> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TalkItem talkItem = items.get(position);
            CheckBox checkBox;
            TextView topText;
            TextView bottomText;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.sessionlistitem, null);
                checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                topText =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                bottomText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

                // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to 
                // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
                convertView.setTag(new TalkItemViewHolder(checkBox, topText, bottomText));

                // If CheckBox is toggled, update the listitem it is tagged with.
                checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                        TalkItem ti = (TalkItem) cb.getTag();
                        ti.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );
                    }
                });
            }
            // Reuse existing row view
            else {
                // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call findViewById().
                TalkItemViewHolder viewHolder = (TalkItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
                topText = viewHolder.getTopText();
                bottomText = viewHolder.getBottomText();
            }


            // Tag the CheckBox with the Planet it is displaying, so that we can
            // access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
            if(talkItem!=null){
                if(checkBox!=null){
                    checkBox.setTag(talkItem); 
                    // Display item data
                    checkBox.setChecked( talkItem.isChecked() );
                }
                if(topText!=null)
                    topText.setText(talkItem.getAuthor());
                if(bottomText!=null)
                    bottomText.setText(talkItem.getTitle());
            } 
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);              
            return convertView;
        }     
    }
    public class TalkItemViewHolder {
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private TextView topText;
        private TextView bottomText;

        public TalkItemViewHolder(){}
        public TalkItemViewHolder(CheckBox checkBox, TextView topText, TextView bottomText){
            this.checkBox = checkBox;
            this.topText = topText;
            this.bottomText = bottomText;
        }

        public CheckBox getCheckBox(){
            return checkBox;
        }

        public TextView getTopText(){
            return topText;
        }

        public TextView getBottomText(){
            return bottomText;
        }

        public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox){
            this.checkBox = checkBox;
        }

        public void setTopText(TextView topText){
            this.topText = topText;
        }

        public void setBottomText(TextView bottomText){
            this.bottomText = bottomText;
        }

    }

    public class TalkItem {
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private boolean checked = false;


        public TalkItem(){
            title = "";
            author = "";
        }
        public TalkItem(String title, String author, boolean checked){
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public String getTitle(){
            return title;
        }

        public String getAuthor(){
            return author;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title){
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void setAuthor(String author){
            this.author = author;
        }

        public boolean isChecked(){
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked){
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public void toggleChecked(){
            checked = !checked;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my parent layout for the main view, entitled `session_view.xml`

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sessionviewlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sessiontitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sessionlocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sessiontitle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sessionlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sessionlocation"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:dividerHeight="3.0sp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:minHeight="1in" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the layout for each item in the list, entitled `sessionlistitem.xml`

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.99"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My custom listSelector `list_selector.xml` is

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

`list_selector_pressed.xml` is

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>   
</shape>
```

`strings.xml` is

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="app_name">My APP</string>
    <color name="gray">#aaaaaa</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="blue">#5BB5D7</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: That really sounds like something is going wrong in your adapter in the view recycling somewhere, but if it is I can't see where....

Comment: Does the scrolling action require the focus to be enabled in a specific way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ArrayAdapter` needs to be initialized after everything is added.  Specifically, the lines:

```
this.m_adapter = new MyListView(this, R.layout.sessionlistitem, m_talks);
lv.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

should have been the last lines in the `onCreate` method, after all of the `m_talks.add(...)`.

There wasn't anything wrong with the `xml` layout files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by setting your listview height to wrap_content in your relative layout. That doesn't really make sense for a listview because its content is usually larger than its on-screen height. One possible fix here is to change your top RelativeLayout into a LinearLayout, then the height settings on the listview can be:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Which will use all remaining space for the listview.

Comment: Did it have any effect, or just exactly the same? You could also try setting a small static height as a test, like 50dp and see if you see any scrolling. If not, then it's probably something else.

Comment: Whoops, I am actually able to scroll, but not like a regular listView. I am using the emulator and I can only scroll when  I hold down the click button and also sweep my fingers.  The default ListView scrolls with a sweeping motion over the screen.  But my application doesn't.  A possibly related issue is that I would also like my rows to be focused and change color when my fingers are hovering over the row items.

Comment: I edited the main entry to rephrase my issue with focusing on ListView items and scrolling with the sweeping motion.